# Macbook Air system fails and fsck does not work

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, startup, mount

My macbook air 13 (mid 2013) cannot boot correctly. It stops at the Apple logo loading screen.
After getting into the single user mode, here is the error I got by running`fsck -fy` (didn't find any information about the error code):
[image]

After running the command `mount -uw /`, I got this and the process just hangs there:[image]

I think because of some failed system files or potentially damaged hard drive, the system cannot  boot or mount the main drive (macintosh HD). I also tried to re-install the OS in the recover mode and it was just stuck during the initial process (seems related to the mounting problem). I also used the `diskutil repairVolume` command, but the process went on for 10 hours without any results (guess it's also stuck).
Any ideas about how to solve this problem? Is there a way to force formating the main drive without mounting it?

Updates (9-27-2020): After two days of research and seeking for advice, I finally solved the problem by erasing the whole drive and re-installing the OS. It was actually not as straightforward as it sounds. Neither the re-install option in the Recovery Mode nor the Internet Recovery worked. Both processes were stuck at some point because the system couldn't mount/recognize the main hard drive (due to the failed file system I think). I couldn't delete/write anything in the command line either.

So I decided to boot from a USB drive. I first tried using a MacOS boot drive, but the process was still stuck. Then I tried a Windows boot drive and it still didn't work. Finally a Ubuntu boot drive went through and I managed to erase the hard drive and installed a Ubuntu. The hard drive became okay. Then I re-installed the Mac OS through the Internet Recovery.

Conclusion: it is a problem of failed file systems, not a hardware problem (luckily). The disk repair tools provided by Apple seems not be able to fix it.

Comment: You can boot to recovery mode and reformat the drive.

Comment: @SteveChambers Not really. After opening the disk utility in the recovery mode, it's just hanging there without showing any disks.

Comment: If Disk Utility hangs or shows no disks, that suggests the drive is hosed.